# Is Java's Timer task guaranteed not to run concurrently?

Tags: java, concurrency, timer

```
new Timer(...).schedule(task)
```

Is `task` guaranteed to be run by a single thread at any given time?

Comment: Ouch, a down vote for RTFM? You'd have to down vote almost all the questions on Stack Overflow then.

Comment: Stackoverflow is TFM !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

> Corresponding to each Timer object is a single background thread that is used to execute all of the timer's tasks, sequentially. Timer tasks should complete quickly. If a timer task takes excessive time to complete, it "hogs" the timer's task execution thread. This can, in turn, delay the execution of subsequent tasks, which may "bunch up" and execute in rapid succession when (and if) the offending task finally completes.

So, yes, you get a new Thread (separate from the caller's thread). Every task in that timer shares the same thread.

Answer (score 4):

There is a single thread per Timer, so the answer to your question is yes

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. They all run on a same background thread corresponded to the Timer object in sequence. BUT two different Timer instances will run (I believe) on different threads, so you have to save reference to a timer object to schedule more tasks sequentialy.